# Sort an array by the last couple characters of its values?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

In PHP, how might one sort an array by the last couple of characters of its values? Take, for example, the following array:

```
$donuts[0] = "Chocolate 02";
$donuts[1] = "Jelly 16";
$donuts[2] = "Glazed 01";
$donuts[3] = "Frosted 12";
```

After the sort, the array would look like this (note the order based on the last two characters of each value... also note the rewritten indexes):

```
$donuts[0] = "Glazed 01";
$donuts[1] = "Chocolate 02";
$donuts[2] = "Frosted 12";
$donuts[3] = "Jelly 16";
```

I can't seem to find a built-in function that can do this and have been racking my brain for the simplest and most efficient way to get this accomplished. Help! And thanks!

Comment: Can you edit these arrays?  Maybe into an associative array instead or is this the value you are receiving?

Comment: @Chad Unfortunately, no, I cannot edit the arrays. I am given the array in the above format. From there I can programmatically do whatever I want, but I can't modify that original array.

Comment: @MarcB Hmm... how would that work? I'm baffled by the $cmp_function part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
header('Content-Type: Text/Plain');
$donuts[0] = "Chocolate 02";
$donuts[1] = "Jelly 16";
$donuts[2] = "Glazed 01";
$donuts[3] = "Frosted 12";

print_r($donuts);

usort($donuts, function ($a, $b){
    return substr($b, -2) - substr($a, -2);
});

print_r($donuts);
```

**NOTE**

1. To convert from highest to smallest:

   ```
   return substr($b, -2) - substr($a, -2);
   ```
2. This answer make an assumption that the last 2 characters is to be used.

**UPDATE**

To make it work on PHP version 5.2, change the `return` part to:

```
return substr($b, strlen($b) - 2) - substr($a, strlen($a) - 2);
```

Comment: YES!!! That does the trick! I need to wrap my head around the usort cmp thingy. Regardless, that works well. Many thanks.

Comment: Ugh... I just discovered that the server I'm going to be running this on is PHP 5.2. I've been testing on 5.3. This is broken on the 5.2 server... any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

```
usort($donuts, function ($a, $b) {
    preg_match('/\d+$/', $a, $matchA);
    preg_match('/\d+$/', $b, $matchB);
    return $matchA[0] - $matchB[0];
});
```

This would of course benefit greatly from some preprocessing, so you don't need to `preg_match` the same strings over and over.