# PHP: sorting array by number

Tags: php, arrays

How to sort the array by last number?
String:

```
152908----abcd----5
152918----abcd----4
152938----abcd----1
152970----abcd----3
152972----abcd----2
```

Make them like this:

```
152938----abcd----1
152972----abcd----2
152970----abcd----3
152918----abcd----4
152908----abcd----5
```

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900283/sort-an-array-by-the-last-couple-characters-of-its-values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900283/sort-an-array-by-the-last-couple-characters-of-its-values)

Comment: Is the length of the string value always the same, and/or is it only ever the last digit that you want to sort by or could the sort be on any number at all?

Comment: Sort string by last digit/number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`usort`](http://php.net/usort). You can give it an array and a custom compare function.